# Charm AutoCompleteTextField setSelectedItem

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

`AutoCompleteTextField` accepts a `List<T>` for its completer function. 
While it can be initialized with a String, it seems not to be possible to initialize it with an object of type T, because `AutoCompleteTextField.valueProperty` is readOnly and there is no `SelectionModel`.

```
public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication {

@Override
public void init() {
    ObservableList<Person> persons = getPersons();
    Person defaultPerson = persons.get(0);
    FilteredList<Person> personsFiltered = new FilteredList<>(persons);

    AutoCompleteTextField<Person> txtPerson = new AutoCompleteTextField<>();
    txtPerson.setCompleter(s ->
    {
        personsFiltered.setPredicate(person -> person.name.contains(s));
        return personsFiltered;
    });

    TextField txtSelectedPerson = new TextField();
    txtPerson.valueProperty().addListener((obsValue, p, p1) -> txtSelectedPerson.setText(p1.name));

    Button btnSave = new Button("SAVE");
    btnSave.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        Person selectedPerson = txtPerson.getValue(); //if no autocomplete suggestion was selected, valueProperty is empty
        // save selectedPerson
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(txtPerson, txtSelectedPerson, btnSave);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () ->
    {

        View view = new View(root) {
            @Override
            protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
                appBar.setTitleText("AutoCompleteTest");
            }
        };

        view.setOnShowing(e -> txtPerson.setText(defaultPerson.name));  // here I would like to set the person object instead
                                                                        // of its string representation
        return view;
    });
}

private ObservableList<Person> getPersons() {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("person1"), new Person("person2"), new Person("person3"));
}

private static class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the control's [JavaDoc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.1.0/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/AutoCompleteTextField.html)? It shows a sample that uses `Person`, and attaches a listener to `valueProperty` to get the selected value.

Comment: It's not about getting the value but setting the value. I would like to initialize the AutoCompleteField with an object T when a view is shown. I could initialize it with a String, but then I would have to map the name back to the object when I want to retrieve it

Comment: Can you post a code snippet with that?

Comment: Code snippet added

Comment: If I get it right, you want to override `AutoCompleteTextField::setText`, which in turns comes from `TextField::setText`, that only allows a String?

Comment: Basically I want to initialize the `AutoCompleteTextField` with an object, so I can retrieve an object via the valueProperty, even when no autocomplete suggestion was selected  (I've edited my question)

Comment: The JavaDoc already says about `valueProperty` that `if no value has been selected this property will be null`, and you can't preselect any of the items, so it only works if you open the popup and select one.

Comment: Ok, so the AutoCompleteTextField is rather intended as a pure search field than kind of a like an editable ComboBox with autocomplete function. Any ideas how to workaround the popover issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353023/charm-4-0-0-popupview-shows-up-only-once

Comment: It should be fixed in the next release. In the meantime, yes, it is possible coming with a workaround based on a lookup to get the popup layer.