# DropdownButton control not working

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Does anyone know of any sample gluon-mobile projects with a DropdownButton control? I'm trying to create a View with a DropdownButton in the center, but after I select an option the control freezes and won't let me select any other menu items. I'm using Gluon Charm 4.0.1 and testing with "gradle run" (Desktop mode). DropdownButton seems like such a simple control I hope there's a simple fix. Thanks in advance for any help.

Sample code:

```
package org.bytabit.ft.fxui.client;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.DropdownButton;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(String name) {
        super(name);

        DropdownButton dropdownButton = new DropdownButton();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Choice 1");
        dropdownButton.getItems().addAll(menuItem, new MenuItem("Choice 2"), new MenuItem("Choice 3"), new MenuItem("Choice 4"));
        dropdownButton.setSelectedItem(menuItem);

        setCenter(dropdownButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353023/charm-4-0-0-popupview-shows-up-only-once

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like it was fixed in the latest version of the Charm library. I just had to update from Charm 4.0.1 to 4.2.0. Thanks Gluon team!

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0"
...
```

Charm 4.2.0 release announcement [here](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-mobile-4-2-0-gluon-ide-plugins-released).